# How I can click on element which appers when I mouse over?

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver, automated-tests

I am trying to execute below code, I am able to perform mouse over but unable to click on element which appears after mouse over.

```
System.out.println("start");
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\SeleniumGecko\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/");
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement mouse=driver.findElement(By.className("nav-line-2"));
action.moveToElement(mouse).perform();
Thread.sleep(10000);
WebElement clickElement= driver.findElement(By.className("nav-a"));// the Element which I want clcik
action.moveToElement(clickElement).click().perform();
System.out.println("stop");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Actions` class, and you want to click on some element, you need to use `build()` method.

Replace the second last line with as below:

```
action.moveToElement(clickElement).click().build().perform();
```

This should now click on the element.